# Is there any way to open the picturehub app for a photo on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, launcher

In my current app, I'd like to use the XNA MediaLibrary classes to save an image to the user's picture hub folders - that's easy enough...

However, then I'd like to open that picture in the PictureHub - especially so that the user can then easily share that photo.

Is there any way anyone knows to do this? I've looked and found nothing so far - and I tried MediaPlayerLauncher (but that failed - it's really built for music/video).

Comment: Try the use the MediaLirbary and the Sharing Tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... this has been open long enough.

The answer on Mango 7.1/7.5 level seems to be a clear "no"

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can achieve the same in 2 ways ,

1. By using photoChooser Task
2. Using Image control in you application

1.PhotoChooserTask :

using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks; use this name space

```
PhotoChooserTask objPhotoChooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
objPhotoChooser.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(PhotoChooserCompleted);
objPhotoChooser.Show();

private void PhotoChooserCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e) 
    { 
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK) 
        { 
            var img = new BitmapImage(); 
            img.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto); 
        } 
    }
```

you can use the Cameracapture task to add real time picture sharing to you application.

2.Image control using in you applciation page

you have to use the Image control in you application page to accomplish the same.

page.xaml looks like

```
<Image x:Name = "imagecontrol" width ="300" height = "300" Stretch = "Fill">
```

Add these namespaces

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

behind this code looks like in xaml.cs file in the appropriate hanlder

```
MediaLibrary ml = new MediaLibrary();

if (ml.Pictures.Count > 0)
{
     System.IO.Stream sm = ml.Pictures[0].GetImage();
     BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
     bmp.SetSource(sm);
     imagecontrol.Source = bmp;
}
```

This always set first picture in MediaLibrary, change this code according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks - but sadly I don't see how either of these options helps me achieve the result I want - I want to get the Pictures Hub to show. To be clear, I don't want to make use of all the sharing functions that the Picture Hub offers to users without having to write the Facebook, Twitter, SkyDrive, etc sharing code myself.

Comment: okay i think i got you requirement now, that you want create application to share the picture, which is launched directly from the picture's Hub. Am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is to access photos , from your application.

But your idea is to launch the application from the Picture hub when user clicks on the options available in the picture hub context.

To do so you have to create and declare your **application as Extensions to picture hub** application this can achieved in the way [described in the following link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202966%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

alternatively link is here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202966%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: Does this suits your requirement ??

Comment: no - I need to launch the picturehub from my application - not the other way around. The flow is: My app will make a picture, My App saves the picture, My app opens picture in PictureHub, user can click share